# Groovy Beta: Python error in Arch Linux install

Tags: ros, python, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the [install instructions](http://ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Arch) for groovy beta and in section 2, when I do:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF
```

I get the following error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/kevin/groovy_underlay/build/devel
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.3") 
-- Could NOT find PY_em (missing:  PY_EM) 
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/empy.cmake:28 (message):
  Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
  installing package 'python-empy'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/all.cmake:136 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How do I get arch to find the python-empy I installed earlier in step 1?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48989/groovy-beta:-python-error-in-arch-linux-install/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out, typo in the instructions, I will fix them. Need to install python**2**-empy:

```
sudo packer -S python2-empy log4cxx gtest
```

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3